# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с перелылаемыми сообщения телеграм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Суть задачи - клиент пишет сообщение боту, сообщение пересылается в группу пользователей (админов). (делаю полный аналог livegram bot)
Эта часть работает только сообщение приходит от имени бота (хотя и показывается что оно пересылаемое).
вот как выглядит:

[image: так выглядит сообщение в группе - автор сообщения - бот (куда было отправлено сообщение пользователем Artem]

Далее, администратор нажимает ответ на это сообщение и пишет текст. Только в поле ответа - уже нету получателя Артема - есть только "бот" и в результате сообщение приходит в бот, но автор - Артем - ничего не видит.

Код который используем вот:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
print('Hi')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привіт, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Ви звернулися до Cтудії Autosecurity. Ми займаємось захистом автомобілів від угону. Чим можемо бути Вам корисні?'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')
@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    user = message.from_user.id
    chat = -1001865025667
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Как включить сервисный режим?", url="https://youtu.be/QCl1rjWn4eE"))
    idbot = 5442607888
    print(f'{user}')
    if message.chat.id != -1001865025667:
        bot.forward_message(chat, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Ваш сообщение обрататывается нашим специалистом, пока нет ответа возможно вы найдете его в наших подсказках', reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='html')
    else:
        bot.forward_message(user, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{message}', parse_mode='html')
        #bot.forward_message(chatе, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

---

В самом сообщении хранится информация forward_from
Но не получается её использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Моя мысль, как такое реализовать:

1. Создаем БД, в ней храним id сообщения в группе и chat_id откуда оно пришло
2. При reply к сообщению, боту возвращается его id, по нему в бд находим chat_id
3. Profit

Как выглядит код:

```
#класс бд
class db:
    def __init__(self, database_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(
            database_file, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
                `message_id` INTEGER,
                `chat_id` INTEGER
            );""")
    def add_message(self, message_id: int, chat_id: int) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES(?,?)',
            (message_id, chat_id)
        )
        self.connection.commit()

    def get_id(self, message_id: int) -> int:
        result=self.cursor.execute(
            'SELECT `chat_id` FROM `messages` WHERE `message_id` = ?',
            (message_id,)
        ).fetchone()
        return result[0]

#далее создаем объект базы данных
db=db('{название файла бд}')

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    markup = {'inline_keyboard':[
        [{'text':'Как включить сервисный режим?', 
          'url':'https://youtu.be/QCl1rjWn4eE'}]
    ]}
    if message.chat.id != -1001865025667:
        bot.forward_message(chat, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        db.add_message(message.message_id, message.chat.id) #добавляем в бд сообщение

    elif message.reply_to_message: #проверяем, является ли сообщение ответом
        bot.copy_message(
            chat_id=db.get_id(message.reply_to_message.message_id), #chat_id, куда отправляем
            from_chat_id=message.chat.id, 
            message_id=message.message_id 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо за ответ, biflé
Я попробовал и использовал такой код:

```js
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
print('Hi')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):
    mess = f'Привіт, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Ви звернулися до Cтудії Autosecurity. Ми займаємось захистом автомобілів від угону. Чим можемо бути Вам корисні?'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')

class db:
    def init(self, database_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(
            database_file, check_same_thread=False)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute(
                """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
                `message_id` INTEGER,
                `chat_id` INTEGER
            );""")
    def add_message(self, message_id: int, chat_id: int) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES(?,?)',
            (message_id, chat_id)
        )
        self.connection.commit()

    def get_id(self, message_id: int) -> int:
        result=self.cursor.execute(
            'SELECT `chat_id` FROM `messages` WHERE `message_id` = ?',
            (message_id,)
        ).fetchone()
        return result[0]

#далее создаем объект базы данных
db=db('{your.db}')

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    chat = -1001865025667
    markup = {'inline_keyboard':[
        [{'text':'Как включить сервисный режим?',
          'url':'https://youtu.be/QCl1rjWn4eE'}]
    ]}
    if message.chat.id != -1001865025667:
        bot.forward_message(chat, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        db.add_message(message.message_id, message.chat.id) #добавляем в бд сообщение

    elif message.reply_to_message: #проверяем, является ли сообщение ответом
        bot.copy_message(
            chat_id=db.get_id(message.reply_to_message.message_id), #chat_id, куда отправляем
            from_chat_id=message.chat.id,
            message_id=message.message_id
        )
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Но выходит ошибка:
File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 37, in get_id
return result[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable